# iOS 10. CoreData insert new object sig ABRT

Tags: swift, core-data, ios10, xcode8-beta2

I tried forEntityName: "Game", "MyApp.Game".

in my dataManagerFile:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
                        let container = appDelegate.persistentContainer

                        let managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
                        for item in items {
                            let word = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MyApp.Game", into: managedObjectContext) as! Game
```

in Game+coreDataProperties file

```
extension Game {

    @nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Game> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Game>(entityName: "Game");
    }
```

in Game+coreDataClass

```
class Game: NSManagedObject {

}
```

I generated files for CoreData using .xcdatamodeld: in object inspector I specified Name: "Game", Class "Game", Module "Current Product Module", codegen "class definition", then I used Editor/create subclass, after I got 3 files I set codegen property to "Manual/None"

I got run-time error: "signal SIGABRT" when trying to cast to Game in:

```
NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MyApp.Game", into: managedObjectContext) as! Game
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also could you advice me a good manual on CoreData, with latest changes applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have made it to work.
This isn't the first issue I have faced while working with CoreData in iOS 10, on xCode Beta.
So here is sequence of steps for adding your entities in xCode 8:
1.When creating your app pick CoreData option, this will create   youAppName.xcdatamodeld file
2. choice youAppName.xcdatamodeld, add Entity button
3. add required attributes
4. use data Model inspector to setup code generation:
Entity Name "Game", Class Name "GameEntity", Module "Current Product  Module", codegen "class definition"
5. cmd + s
6. Editor/create NSManagedObjectSubclass
7. You will get 3 new files:
GameEntity+CoreDataClass
GameEntity+CoreProperties
**COREDATA**
8. Comment out content of the file "**COREDATA**..."
9. youAppName.xcdatamodeld, data Model inspector, now when you have generated files, change Codeine property from "class definition" to "Manual/None"

Here is a code sample on how to add new objects:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
                        let container = appDelegate.persistentContainer

                        let managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
                        for item in items {
                            let game = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Game", into: managedObjectContext) as! GameEntity
                            game.status = item.status
                            game.rs = item.rs
                            game.score = item.score


                            do {
                                try managedObjectContext.save()
```

here is a code sample on how to remove data:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let container = appDelegate.persistentContainer
        let managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<GameEntity> = GameEntity.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let games = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) 
            for game in games {
                managedObjectContext.delete(game)
            }
```

Comment: You should not be changing the class generation.  It is meant to be left alone and Xcode will keep the class files up to date (or the extensions if you set it that way).  If you turn off the code generation and change your model files they will get out of sync.  BTW, your force cast on entity creation is an indication that something is wrong.  If your code is configured correctly you can create the `Game` entity as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, no one has updated the documentation for the changes in Core Data for iOS 10 yet.  Expect them to start showing up in the next couple of months (Apple included).

Second, with the new changes to Core Data, you should no longer need to cast on creation.  Ideally you can now just do:

```
let word = Game(context: managedObjectContext)
```

And it will do the correct thing.

BTW, You should not need to call the entity "MyApp.Game".  It should be just "Game" and that is probably the core of your error.

Comment: thanks for reply. There are updates for Core Data, but they are a little abbreviated )) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html
I wish I could just do let word = ..., but I am getting compiler errors
yes, I just used "Game"

Comment: There are more updates coming from Apple and their docs.  If you are getting compile error then what compile error are you getting?  That would indicate that there is something wrong in your configuration/model/code somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Xcode 8 automatically generates the classes needed to represent the entities, so you don't have to create them manually.
Instead of:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let container = appDelegate.persistentContainer
    let managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
    for item in items {
         let word = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MyApp.Game", into: managedObjectContext) as! Game
```

You could try this:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let container = appDelegate.persistentContainer
    let managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
    for item in items {
        let word = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Game", into: managedObjectContext) as! Game
```

But make sure to give the proper name to the class in Data Model Inspector
[Setting class name in Data Model Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmryw.png)